# Confused by Java SE8 Predicate.and method

Tags: java, predicate

The following tow code pieces:

The first:

```
    Predicate<Dish> p1 = t -> t.getCalories() > 100;
    Predicate<Dish> p2 = t -> t.getCalories() < 1000;
    menu.stream().filter(p1.and(p2));
```

The second:

```
menu.stream().filter((t -> t.getCalories() > 100).and(t -> t.getCalories() < 1000));
```

The first is ok and compile successfuly.
But the second causes a comiple error:

```
The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
```

What's wrong, I'm confused.

Comment: The compiler has no way of knowing what `(t -> t.getCalories() > 100)` is. You can fix that by explicitly casting to the appropriate functional interface, i.e. `menu.stream().filter(((Predicate<Dish>) (t -> t.getCalories() > 100)).and(t -> t.getCalories() < 1000));`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, it's ok just as you say. But the code is ugly, the compliler is not too smart .